# Git как востановить файлы после удаления?

Tags: windows, git

Удалил файлы после команды `git rm -r -f .`.

Как теперь их востановить? <s>это был первый комит,</s> до этого ни одного комита не было, мы только локально сделали `git add .`, поэтому проект не залился в репозиторий и оттуда востановить не получится.

```
$ git reflog
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

Comment: Судя по рефлогу, коммитов ещё не было. Но если точно был `git add .`, используйте инструкции из ответа по ссылке выше.

Comment: Ну как, помогло?

Answer (score 1):

Доброе утро! Если вы удалили первый локальный коммит, попробуйте

```
git reflog
```

там будет список всех коммитов (в том числе и удаленных), примерно такой

```
1a410ef HEAD@{0}: 1a410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9: updating HEAD
1a410ef HEAD@{0}: 1a410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9: updating HEAD
1a410ef HEAD@{0}: 1a410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9: updating HEAD
```

берете оттуда номер коммита и

```
git reset --hard номерКоммита
```

PROFIT!!!

Comment: $ git reflog
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet

получил такую ошибку
просто у нас до этого ни одного комита не было, мы только локально сделали git add .
после поняли что ушли все файлы
добавили git ignore
после хотели удалить комит но удалились все файлы вместе с ним)

Comment: Если нет ни одного коммита, и нет удаленного репозитория, то git тут ничего не восстановит. Он просто про ваш проект и не знает тогда ничего. Надеюсь, вы не успели много накодить.

Comment: тут какая то несостыковка. Коммит был или нет? в любом случае, что есть в папке `.git/objects`?