# восстановление незупушенного коммита

Tags: git

Вообщем такая история:

1. сделал некоторые изменения в репозитории
2. сделал коммит
3. попытался запушить, но обнаружил, что не могу этого сделать, так как на сервере есть более новый коммит
4. сделал `git pull`, прошел автоматический мержинг и сформировался коммит
5. понял, что мне сначала следовало откатить локальный коммит и спуллить все изменения с репозитория, чтобы история выглядела более чистой (без коммита с мержингом
6. сделал `git reset HEAD^^`
7. сделал `git checkout .`
8. все изменения 2-ух последних коммитов улетучились, а я понял, что сделал какую-то *****
9. видя, что моя ветка `behind by 2 commits` подумал, что нужно сделать просто `git pull`
10. сделал `git pull` и переместился на `master` с репозитория, при этом без моих изменений, который я пытался закомитить

Итак: как восстановить изменения? Я знаю, что их можно восстановить, но не знаю как

Comment: Надо было делать свои изменения делать в отдельной ветке, а в мастер потом переносить с помощью rebase. А теперь уже смотреть reflog, искать пропавший коммит с изменениями и переключаться на него https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588765

Comment: @andreymal я это прекрасно знаю (как надо делать), но, увы, политика у нас другая. А по поводу reflog - хорошая идея

Answer (score 3):

Если сборки мусора ещё не произошло, то:

1. Найти коммит по коммит-месаджу:

   ```sh
   $ git reflog --all | grep 'my message'
   ```
2. Предположим, хеш коммита `abc123`. Черипикнуть:

   ```sh
   $ git cherry-pick --edit abc123
   ```